# Remove fragment from activity when clicking button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Currently, my main activity has a description field which opens a fragment when the user clicks on the description. On the fragment there is a text field and a button, when I click the button, I want to close the fragment and go back to my activity.

How can I achieve this?

I have added an onClickListener to my fragment to capture the click on the button. The toast message gets printed, but the fragment is not removed/closed.

```
descDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        });
```

I have the onClickListener in the onCreateView of the fragment. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

I am adding my fragment like this:

```
((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, frag).commit();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the proper fragment and fragment manager classes (not support one or the other way around)?

Comment: A Fragment is inside an Activity, so please clarify "go back to your Activity".

Comment: Are you using AppCompactActivity? then use getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: @Shaishav you are correct, I should be using the support fragment manager, I have made the change but it still does not work.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a MainActivity which has a layout with a bunch of textviews and buttons, when the user clicks a certain button, a fragment is added overtop of everything. Now this fragment has a dismiss button which I want to close the fragment and go back to my MainActivity layout, does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this first add the fragment to backstack like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then remove the fragment like this:-

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
      if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
      fm.popBackStack();
}
```

to remove all fragments

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
      for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
      fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think my issue was that I wasn't adding the fragment to the backstack correctly. After that change the popBackStack worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately it does not remove the fragment. See my edited post for how I am adding the fragment, maybe I am not doing that part correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

Answer (score 0):

try to using following code:

```
   public void fragmentReplace() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(new TermsAndConditionFragment().getClass().getName()) != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(new TermsAndConditionFragment().getClass().getName(),
                        FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }  else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
```

in main Activity in descDismiss button clickListener insert below code:

```
 descDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fragmentReplace();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to add fragments:

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
frmInicio fragment = new frmInicio();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_menu_layout, fragment,"frm_inicio");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My way to remove

```
//frm_inicio
Fragment frm = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("frm_inicio");
if(frm!=null){
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(frm);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```